# How do I make a bat do something else if executed with a flag/switch (Title is probably vague)

Tags: batch-file

So, I've been working on a batch script that essentially helps you with [youtube-dl](https://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/), essentially filing out all the data it needs to download into a directory. I want to be able to make a special shortcut that launches it, and instead of doing what it normally does, I want it to go through a text file (for example, let's call it update list.txt) and update playlists when that shortcut is run. I don't want to make another batch file that does this (for simplicity for user).

Here's what I have so far:

```
@echo off
:loop
title Welcome to CCF_100's youtube-dl helper!
set /A loop=loop+1
echo.Times Looped: %loop%
cd %~dp0
set /p input=Enter YouTube ID, URL, or Playlist ID: 
set /p Output_Dir=Enter Directory you want to save in (Directory will be 
created if it does not exist): 
set /p flags=Enter flags (Optional): 
if exist %Output_Dir%\ (goto Do_the_thing) else (goto make_directory)


:make_directory
mkdir "%Output_Dir%"
if /I %loop% LEQ 2 goto Do_the_thing
explorer "%Output_Dir%"

:Do_the_thing
title CCF_100's ytdl helper: currently downloading: %input% to %Output_Dir%
youtube-dl.exe -i -U %flags% -o "%Output_Dir%\%%(title)s - %%(id)s.%%(ext)s" 
%input% 
set /p loop=Successfully downloaded file(s). Download more?
if /i %loop%==y goto loop
if /i %loop%==Y goto loop
if /i %loop%==n goto end
if /i %loop%==N goto end

:end
exit
```

And yes I know the last two if statements are unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the arguments of a batchfile by reading the value of `%n` with n being a number between 0 and 9 or an asterisk. 0 is the batch-file itself (in the sense of the path to it) and the asterisk means any additional argument (excluding the batch-file-path).

So with that you can check for the contents of `%1` and see if it is the flag you thought of or existent at all:

```
REM Demo only!
@echo off
if "%1"=="" (
  echo no flags set
) ELSE (
  echo flag set: %1
)
```

or change the if in a similar fashion to react to your flag only.